# Email Event Handling in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to implement event on email body i.e when i am sending mail using SmtpClient and after sending mail when user click anywhere in email body need to redirect to another page .

Please Help me.

Comment: Include a link in the email body.

Comment: I want to make entire body as clickable which means user clicks anywhere in email body redirect to another page

Answer (score 2):

For this you have to do few things:

- Construct your mail body as html tags, enclose all contents inside an anchor tag with href points to the site to be redirected to.
- set `IsBodyHtml` property of the `MailMessage` object to `true`
- Send the mail

Try something like this:

```
string mailBodyHtml = "<a href='https://YourSiteName.com'> enclose the whole content here </a>
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("fromAddress", "toAddress", "subject here", mailBodyHtml);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: i have done this but the link is applied only till text but i want that the entire body window part of mail must be clickable

Comment: @shyamaWadhwani: I don't get what you meant by `entire body window`, are you trying to generate spam mails?

Comment: This is probably as close as you will get. There is no (or very little) support for javascript in email clients. Advanced CSS options will also be limited due to only basic CSS support in email clients.

Comment: No i dont want to generate spam mails i just want entire email body part  clickable i.e user clicks any where in body need to be redirected irrespective till just text of body.

Comment: @shyamaWadhwani: That is what I suggested in the above answer.  create an html of Whatever things you want to add/send in the mail body, then enclose those tags inside the `<a href ='..` tags. So the whole things will act as a link, have you tried the suggestion?

Comment: Yes but the link is till my text only it not necessary that user click on text i want that user click anywhere apart from text also

Comment: What are all the contents you have other than that text? why don't you add them under the anchor tags?

Comment: @un-lucky mostly text,hyperlinks,images

Comment: Looking at: https://jsfiddle.net/bdah8c7p/ the only problem you should face is any window after the end of the content. Are the hyperlinks going to the same location as "the whole body"?

Comment: @shyamaWadhwani: update your post with current code, let's have a look

Comment: @un-lucky following is my code                                   sb.Append("hello"+"</br>");
              sb.Append("hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello" + "</br>");
                //  Mymessage.Body="<a href="http://localhost:53890/WebForm2.aspx?emailId=" + txt1.Text + "'">"
                Mymessage.Body = "<a style='text-decoration: none; color:black;hover:black;' href='http://localhost:53890/WebForm2.aspx?emailId=" + txt1.Text + "''> "+sb.ToString() +"  </a>";

Comment: @shyamaWadhwani: I don't find any images or any other things outside the `<a`, Honestly I don't understand your specific requirements. sorry

Comment: @shyamaWadhwani: still have issues that need to clarify means contact me, contact details displayed in my profile